# VB.NET DataGrid not showing first row data from database

Tags: vb.net, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to populate my database table in a datagrid.
Now I am able to populate it but the problem here is it only showing the second row data onwards only. The first row data is not showing in the table.
I double checked my database table its showing I have 3 rows of data but in the datagrid its only showing 2 rows of data only. I did my research on the web before asking the question here but I could not find any solution from the web search.

Here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid Background="#FF006E8C">
    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="0,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="695" FontSize="16" Background="White"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelLoginName" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="552,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="userDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="265" Width="640"/>

</Grid>
```

Here is my vb code:

```
Private Sub Windows_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    labelLogin = loginName
    labelLoginName.Content = labelLogin
    Dim query As String
    query = "select * from users"
    reader = db.QueryCommand(query)

    If Not IsNothing(reader) Then
        If reader.HasRows() Then
            While reader.Read()
                userDataGrid.ItemsSource = reader
            End While
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No data")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error at reader")
    End If
```

Can someone help me on this please. I did this by following the tutorial from this tutorial video in youtube: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRdhgzQlC7w)

Tq.

Comment: The way you're loading the data doesn't really make sense. You should create a `DataTable`, call its `Load` method and pass the data reader, then assign the `DataTable` to the `ItemSource`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry I cant understand. can you give me a simple example.

Comment: If you can't understand "create an object of this type, call this method, pass this argument and set this property" then you need to spend some time learning the basics.  Those are fundamental instructions that anyone should be able to carry out. We shouldn't have to teach the basics every time we answer a question. If you ask someone how to bake a cake, they should have to explain how to open a packet of flour and put the contents in a bowl.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved it by removing the while loop from my function.

```
If Not IsNothing(reader) Then
    If reader.HasRows() Then
        userDataGrid.ItemsSource = reader
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No data")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Error at reader")
End If
```